# In what scientific article, website or book can I find a list of the differences of the prime numbers less than the previous prime number to this one.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for a scientific article, website, or book that has a complete list of the following sequence:

$s (a_{n}) = p_{n + 1} -p_{n}$ with $n≥1$

A scientific article, website or book that has a complete list of the values ​​of $π (x)$ would also be of great help to me.

Comment: With a tiny bit of programming you can generate this list from a list of primes (not to mention that you can generate the primes too).

Comment: Of course, but where can I get a code to help me with this?

Comment: You should know there can’t be a complete list. To find primes fast, look up “Sieve if Eratosthenes”. You wouldn’t store a list of primes - you can find primes in a range of 200 million integers in a second easily (and in a range of say 4 billion with a good computer and some programming effort).

Comment: If you  google "list of the differences of the prime numbers" from your title the first hit shows these are known as "prime gaps". So now if you google "list of prime gaps" you quickly find the OEIS page in your accepted answer, and much more. It is expected that you perform such obvious searches before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prime gaps: differences between consecutive primes.](https://oeis.org/A001223)

Comment: and https://oeis.org/A001223/b001223.txt will give the first 100,000 terms but it is not complete